# iOS CoreData fetchRequest with order column diacritic sensitive

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, diacritics

I want to fetch data from `User` table and I want to get the result ordered by first name column  that contains french accents (é, à ....)

Example :

postresql return the result in this order :

```
ANDRIVET

ANDRÉ

ANDUEZA
```

but by doing this :

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"User"];
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]];
```

I have the result in this order :

```
ANDRÉ

ANDRIVET

ANDUEZA
```

Comment: try using the selector: localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:

Comment: i tried to use it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a closer look...

As far as i know, E (with it's accents) comes before I. So the output from Xcode is correct. The postresql is wrong.

Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_alphabet - The accents are not considered separate letters. It only seems postresql misinterprets them